# Is "atmospheric geostationary satellite" feasible with current technology?

Tags: energy, satellites, solar-wind

Meaning by "atmospheric geostationary satellite" a vehicle capable of hovering 30 km above Earth surface, hence insde atmosphere, for unlimited time, making use of air propellers, solar panels and batteries.

How much energy is needed to keep an object steady in air at 30 km above surface?

There are two possibilities: a plane-like vehicle, flying in circle, using wings to stay up; an helicopter-like vehicle, hovering.

Comment: Don't forget a hot-air ballon like object using, well, hot air, to stay up!
Plus I'm sure people will come up with others.

Comment: Ballons are not designed to stay up "for ever" like a satellite.

Comment: But your very idea, of using solar panels/ batteries etc. could also be used to power a heat source to keep the hot-air ballon up.
I would wager it takes far less energy in fact to keep a hot-air baloon up at 30km than an airplane, say, for an extended period of time.
Maybe we have a next question on our hands!

Comment: Typically a "satellite" implies orbiting at a speed sufficient to avoid falling to the ground.  Balloons and airplanes require energy or lift (density) to stay aloft.  You can't be geostationary except at a specific altitude.  But for your putative 30 km vehicle, the "energy  required" is completely undefinable, since it depends on mass, wind variation, and more.  A large kite (with a very low mass cable) might be able to stay aloft purely on the local winds.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.  The atmosphere is a rough place. Winds at that height blow about 12 to 20 m/s.  To stay stationary over a spot on the planet you would have to compensate for the winds and the rotation of the Earth which would take significant power.  Much more than solar panels or batteries could supply.

Comment: You wouldn't have to compensate for the rotation of the earth - for the same reason you don't on the ground.

Comment: @MartinBeckett there are atmospheric sheers due to different viscosities which would be obvious to any thing trying to hold stationary over the ground.  This would need continuous compensation.

Comment: Would't going AROUND whole world cost more energy than staying steady? An electric solar plane capable of flying all around the world was built in 2012 or 2013, IIRC.

Comment: @jumpjack a plane wouldn't be able to be stationary either and not at an altitude of 30km.

Comment: I just read of internet.org, a Facebook project for steady drones flying at 20000m to provide internet connectivity. I wonder how much energy a transponder requires...

Comment: @jumpjack - in the stratosphere there is a predictable and stable jetstream - going around the world (in a certain direction) requires almost no energy - staying still would require a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just adding to user6972's answer.

Tie a balloon to an anchor on the ground. Tethered like this it will be flying over a relatively limited area of Earth. It can stay like that as long as:

- There is enough energy to keep it afloat. For a normal, regular, everyday balloon that means you have to supply fuel to it continuously to heat the air inside it. You could have a gasbag full of helium ("lighter" than air for the same temperature, mostly), or you could have a solar powered minihelicopter, but those take maintenance to keep up;
- Nothing takes it down. Refer to user6972's answer. At some point, the weather is going to be bad for your geostationery atmospheric device.

I think the only reason no one has ever done so for a very long span of time is because it is costly. Most things that need to be high up in the atmosphere in a permanente manner are kept so by being placed on top of a radio tower.

Food for thought: I think the concept for the space elevator partially matches what you picture in your question. You cold at the very least tie something to the elevator's tether midway through the atmosphere. Now, the space elevator poses a series of yet unsolved technologic challenges. If I recall, many of them have to do with keeping the tether whole within the atmosphere (too many forces acting on it).

Comment: most weather occurs in the troposphere. At 30km, you wouldn't have to worry so much about that

Comment: That's true, but I am suggesting a sort of anchoring. Weather could break or otherwise damage the tether, or pull it down.

Answer (score 0):

30 kilometers above the earth, the air is more than 50 times less dense, a baloon or a plane would be 50 times less able to fly there.

The answer is no, it's impractical, and space satellites are going to be more precise too as they can have masses of energy, massive weight, no vibrations, etc.